# Read multiple sections of data in file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file that has data in multiple table-like format (not formatted as an excel table though) and I need to read this data into a singular dataframe.

the spreadsheet looks something like this, with one table of data on top of the other:

```
Commodities Cashflows

Heating Oil
Counterparty Ref#   TradeDate  Commodity    Price  MTM
------------ ----   ---------  ----------   -----  ----
xxx          DF9-1  23-Sep-19  Heating Oil  10.00  10,000
xxx          DF9-2  23-Sep-19  Heating Oil  10.00  10,000
xxx          DF9-3  23-Sep-19  Heating Oil  10.00  10,000
xxx          DF9-4  23-Sep-19  Heating Oil  10.00  10,000

WTI-IPE
Counterparty Ref#   TradeDate  Commodity    Price  MTM
------------ ----   ---------  ----------   -----  ----
xxx          DF9-1  23-Sep-19  WTI-IPE      10.00  10,000
xxx          DF9-1  23-Sep-19  WTI-IPE      10.00  10,000
xxx          DF9-1  23-Sep-19  WTI-IPE      10.00  10,000
xxx          DF9-1  23-Sep-19  WTI-IPE      10.00  10,000
```

the Commodity name labeling the data is different all the time, so I cannot just search for those keywords and begin reading from that point. My first thought was to search for the first column of the table which is always the same like this:

```
def find_start_of_file(file):

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
            if line.startswith('Counterparty'):
                return line_num
```

but that will always start at the first data set, and read unnecessary data afterwards. How could I parse through and read the rest of the data as well and put it in one dataframe?

Comment: IIRC, that's your third post about the same topic and I don't understand why you insist to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) an `.xlsx` file as if it was plain text. You can instead try something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0ZcX.png) using pandas (*/openpyxl under the hood*). NB: This assumes that the cell holding *"Commodities Cashflows"* is located at `A1`.

Comment: Why not go through the file (presumably CSV) and build a List of start, stop line numbers, then loop with `read_csv` with appropriate `skip_rows` and `nrows` values, clean-up the DF, store each DF in a List. Then `concat` all the DFs in the List.

Comment: @Timeless it is an xls file, and the reason I use open is because I did not know it was possible to find the starting point of a file with pandas read functions. I use open to dynamically find a line number to pass to the read functions. I am quite new to using python so I am just trying to learn how to do things more efficiently

Comment: In this case, make sure to have [`xlrd`](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) installed (`pip install xlrd`) and change `"*.xlsx"` to `"*.xls"` in the code I shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can us the below code to extract your excel to one Dataframe.

[MY Excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kQan.png)

```
import pandas as pd
def read_multiple_tables(excel_file):
    dataframes = []
    with pd.ExcelFile(excel_file) as xl:
        # Read each sheet individually
        for sheet_name in xl.sheet_names:
            df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheet_name)

            # Find header row (assuming headers are consistent across tables)
            header_row = df.index[df.apply(pd.isna).all(axis=1)].tolist()

            # If header row found, extract table data
            if header_row:
                dataframes.append(df.iloc[header_row[0] + 1:].copy())  # Skip header

    # Concatenate DataFrames and reset index (if needed)
    combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

    return combined_df
# Example usage
excel_file = "DatasetCROP.xlsx"
combined_df = read_multiple_tables(excel_file)
combined_df.head()
```